# Ruby on rails cant find coffee-script.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I made a new ruby on rails project, and I did the exact same thing yesterday and everything worked fine. Today I created a new project to do it again, and it doesn't work. It says the file doesn't exist. I reinstalled ruby on rails from railsinstaller.org, and still it wont work.

Is there something I need to do?

When I run 127.0.0.1:3000/statuses I get this

```
No such file or directory - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-source-1.6.2/lib/coffee_script/coffee-script.js
      (in c:/treebook/app/assets/javascripts/statuses.js.coffee)

    Extracted source (around line #6):

    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Treebook</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
    9: <body>
```

Any help would be appreictared

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: does the below answer helps you?

Comment: no, it diddnt. I solved the issue by copying the script from a previous version into the directory. It works fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

check you have added

```
//= require_tree .
```

in your application.js, if it's not added add it.

Or else

If you want to include all your js in your layouts, then do the following in your "application.html.erb":

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>
```

for more on javascript_include_tag refer to [rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/JavascriptTagHelpers.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag).